# brew update fails on El Capitan 10.11.3

Tags: homebrew

When updating homebrew with `brew update`, I get the following :

`Error: Fetching /usr/local failed!`

After some digging out and `brew doctor` recommendations I did this :

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local`

It's still not working.
Please help what to do.

Comment: Okay, fixed it using `sudoankit$ sudo chflags norestricted /usr/local && sudo chown $(whoami):admin /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local`
Now it works, El Capitan changes permission.

Comment: Is this one command or multiple? I think you have a mistake in it, it's not working with me.

Comment: @dima which command did you use?

Comment: oh thank you. i uninstalled brew and installed it back again. it worked with me that way.

Comment: I had similar issues with executing git commands, updating zshell and so on.
Disabling the system integrity protection helped with that: 
`csrutil disable` in recovery mode.
you could then fix your permissions and turn the integrity protection back on: `csrutil enable`.

[digitizor.com/fix-homebrew-permissions-osx-el-capitan](http://digitizor.com/fix-homebrew-permissions-osx-el-capitan/) explains a bit more about what to do.